# two database sorting with yii

Tags: sorting, yii

I got 2 models: Category and News. Each News has Category related in tbl_category. In my **news** view file, records are sorted by desc with CActiveDataProvider. Now I want to sort data DESC, but can't handle it. Here's view file of Category.

```
<div id="newsy">
<?php $this->renderPartial('_news',array('news'=>$model->news));?>  /calling _news view
</div>
```

I'm renderPartial view in category, ex. 1 (host/category/1), it gives all News related with id=1, but it isn't sorted by create_time desc. Is there any way to display data sorted w/o DataProvider? Below _news.php view from /views/category folder. Where should I change sorting for this?

```
<?php foreach($news as $news): ?>
<div class="c"><img src="../images/news/news<?php echo CHtml::encode($news>id); ?><?php echo CHtml::encode($news->image);?>" /></div>
<h2 class="n"><?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($news->name),array('news/view','id'=>$news->id)); ?></h2>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($news->shortDescription); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::link("Comments: ({$news->commentCount})",$news->url.'#comments', array ('class' => 'acom')); ?>
```

I guess we will need action from the Controller:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
    ));
}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want to sort a model by a certain field, you can add a default scope for that model and include an 'order' param in that scope.

For example if you want to always sort your `news` models by `create_time` you could do something like;

```
class News extends CActiveRecord
{
    ...
    public function defaultScope()
    {
        $alias = $this->getTableAlias(false,false);
        return array(
            'order'=>"`$alias`.`create_time` DESC",
        );
    }
    ...
}
```

This will add the `order` param to the `CDbCriteria` for each call made the the database, so your model will always be sorted by `create_time DESC`.

Using the `getTableAlias()` method ensures you always use the correct table alias to prevent sql errors down the line.